# Hot 18 game (modified Blackjack) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, beginner, game, playing-cards

I've just completed my first JavaScript game. I strongly welcome any advice/opinions/insults on how crappy or good my game is.

Do you notice anything that is poorly done?

Is there anything that I can write better/shorter?

Here is a link where you can change the code/test the game/etc. http://labs.codecademy.com/Bnov#:workspace

```
suits = ["spades", "diamonds", "clubs", "hearts"];
deck = [];
var h1, h2, h3, hD, nHands; //global vars

for (var x=0; x<suits.length; x++) { for (var i=2; i<10; i++) { deck.push(i + " of " + suits[x]); } }
function shuffle(deck) {
    for (var i = deck.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
         var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
         var temp = deck[i]; deck[i] = deck[j]; deck[j] = temp; } return deck; }
    shuffle(deck);

function Hand(name, sChips, cChips) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sChips = sChips; // Starting Chips
    this.cChips = cChips; // Current Chip count
}

function numHands() {
nHands = parseInt(prompt("How many hands do you want to play?(1,2 or 3)"), 10);
    if (nHands > 0 && nHands < 4) {
        x = 150000/nHands;
        if (nHands > 0) { h1 = new Hand("First Hand", x, x);
            if (nHands > 1) { h2 = new Hand("Second Hand", x, x);
                if (nHands > 2) { h3 = new Hand("Third Hand", x, x); } }
        hD = new Hand("Dealer"); } }
    else { numHands(); } }

function setBetAmount(hand) {
    hand.betAmount = parseInt(prompt(hand.name + ": " + "Place your bet! (bet between 0 and " + hand.cChips + ")"), 10);
    if (hand.betAmount >= 0 && hand.betAmount <= hand.cChips) {
        return hand.betAmount;
    }
    else { setBetAmount(hand); }
}

function recordBetAmount() {
    if (nHands > 0) { setBetAmount(h1);
        if (nHands > 1) { setBetAmount(h2);
            if (nHands > 2) { setBetAmount(h3); } } } }

function dealtwo() { xy = [deck.shift(), deck.shift()]; return xy; }
function dealone() { yx = deck.shift(); return yx; }

function dealCards() {
    if (nHands > 0) { h1.cards = dealtwo();
        if (nHands > 1) { h2.cards = dealtwo();
            if (nHands > 2) { h3.cards = dealtwo(); } }
    hD.cards = dealtwo(); } }

function addValueOfCards(cards) {
   var yyy = 0;
    for (var x = 0; x < cards.length; x++) {
        wwww = cards[x];
        yyy += parseInt(wwww[0], 10);
    }
    return yyy;    
}

function hitOrStay(cards, hand) {
   var x = addValueOfCards(cards);
    if (x < 17) {
        var option = prompt(hand.name + ": You have " + x + ". Do you want to hit or stay?").toLowerCase();
        if (option === "hit" || option === "h") {
            cards.push(dealone());
            hitOrStay(cards, hand);
        }
        else if (option === "stay" || option === "s") {
            console.log(hand.name + ":  " + hand.cards);
        }
        else {
            hitOrStay(cards, hand);
        }
    }
    else if (x === 17 || x === 18) {
        console.log(hand.name + ":  " + hand.cards);
    }
    else {
        console.log(hand.name + ":  " + hand.cards);
    }
}

function dealerHitOrStay(cards) {
   var x = addValueOfCards(cards);
    if (x < 15) {
        cards.push(dealone());
        dealerHitOrStay(cards);
    }
    else if (x > 14 && x < 19) {
        console.log("Dealer Hand:  " + hD.cards);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Dealer Hand: " + hD.cards);
    }
}

function tableOptions() {
    if (nHands > 0) {
        hitOrStay(h1.cards, h1);
        if (nHands > 1) {
            hitOrStay(h2.cards, h2);
            if (nHands > 2) {
                hitOrStay(h3.cards, h3);
            }
        }
    dealerHitOrStay(hD.cards);
    }
}

function recap() {
    if (nHands > 0) {
        wonOrLost(h1.cards, h1);
        if (nHands > 1) {
            wonOrLost(h2.cards, h2);
            if (nHands > 2) {
                wonOrLost(h3.cards, h3);
            }
        }
    again();
    }
}

function wonOrLost(cards, hand) {
    var x = addValueOfCards(cards);
    var y = addValueOfCards(hD.cards);
    if (x < 19 && (x > y || y > 18)) {
        console.log("\n" + hand.name + ": You Won. (you had " +  x + ", dealer had " + y + ")");
        hand.cChips = hand.cChips + hand.betAmount;
        console.log("            + " + hand.betAmount);
    }
    else if (x < 18 && y < 19 && y > x) {
        console.log("\n" + hand.name + ": You Lost. (you had " + x + ", dealer had " + y + ")");
        hand.cChips = hand.cChips - hand.betAmount;
        console.log("            - " + hand.betAmount);
    }
    else if (x > 18) {
        console.log("\n" + hand.name + ": You Lost. (you busted with " + x + ")");
        hand.cChips = hand.cChips - hand.betAmount;
        console.log("            - " + hand.betAmount);
    }
    else {
        console.log("\n" + hand.name + ": You Tied. (you and dealer both had " + x + ")");
        console.log("            + 0");
    }
}

function again() {
    if (deck.length > 10) {
    xxxx = prompt("Hit Enter to play another round. Type NO, then hit enter, to stop playing.").toLowerCase();
        if (xxxx === "no") {
            console.log("You chose to stop. Thanks for playing!");
        }
        else {
            console.log("____________\n");
            recordBetAmount();
            dealCards();
            tableOptions();
            recap();
        }
    }
    else {
        console.log("\nGame Over! (not enough cards to keep playing)");
        console.log("_________________________________________________");
        if (nHands === 1) {
            x = h1.cChips; }
        else if (nHands === 2) {
            x = h1.cChips + h2.cChips; }
        else if (nHands === 3) {
            x = h1.cChips + h2.cChips + h3.cChips; }
            if (x > 150000) {
                x = x - 150000;
                console.log("Your total score is:  " + x); }
            else { console.log("Your total score is: 0. (which is the worst you can do)"); }
    }
}

numHands();
recordBetAmount();
dealCards();
tableOptions();
recap();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My [remarks about the Ruby version of your code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/37900/9357) also apply to your JavaScript port.

For example `hitOrStay()` should not recurse, because you're just using it as a `goto`.

The players' hands should be stored in an array so that you don't have to write special cases for one, two, or three players.